# Cannot run any game on Steam for Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, steam

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, installed Bumblebee and Steam. Everything worked fine, but now, suddenly, I cannot run any game.

Here is a copy of terminal output:

```
[   ...   ]
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME has been set by the user to: /home/marek/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
ExecCommandLine: "/home/marek/.steam/root/ubuntu12_32/steam steam://open/driverhelperready"
ExecSteamURL: "steam://open/driverhelperready"
Game update: AppID 240 "Counter-Strike: Source", ProcID 2886, IP 0.0.0.0:0
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/marek/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
[   ...   ]
[  dying soon after ]
```

Full log: http://pastebin.com/kpbEXR0y

I tried to reinstall Steam, but it did not help. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug in the packaging of steam components.

From the messages, it'a about not finding a 32bit library on your 64 bit system. That is perfectly normal to search for it, and it may not be found because it's missig, of because the search path is wrong.

There is a similar case discussed here, where the main configuration variable for defining where to search was changed to fix it - so just try the same:

[http://steamcommunity.com/ - Cannot Start Game on Linux](http://steamcommunity.com/app/245410/discussions/0/558751660893317880/?insideModal=1#c558755529768845546)

```
I just modified the "launch_wizardy6.sh" file..(and the others) to get it to use my one.

I just had to alter the last two lines and changed them to the following:

#export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:./libs
exec dosbox -conf dosbox_wiz6.conf -conf dosbox_wiz6_launch_linux.conf -noconsole "$@"
```

If that does not solve it -  it's a configuration problem in steam, so they shoyld fix it and tell you.